# RxJava run part of the flatmap in main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, rx-java2

Hi i am trying to implement a Single observable that chains two requests together.

In between the two requests i make, i notify a callback to update the UI with the response from request one and then launch the next request in the Schedulaers.io thread.

The issue i am having is that it tries to update the UI from the schedulars.io thread too and results to nothing being updated in the ui thread.

i cold wrap the calback on RunOnUiThread code block in android but wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing it?

i checked couroutines and it seems to just deal with putting a block of code in a seperate thread.

Here is my current code

```
override fun getHomeScreenInformation() {
    delegator.requestOne()
            .flatMap { responseOne->
                homeScreenCallBack.onResponseOneRecieved(responseOne)
                delegator.requestTwo()
            }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(
                    {responseTwo-> homeScreenCallBack.onResponseTwoRecieved(responseTwo)},
                    {error -> homeScreenCallBack.onError()}
            )
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apply `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` as many times as necessary:

```
delegator.requestOne()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // <----------------------
        .flatMap { responseOne ->
            homeScreenCallBack.onResponseOneRecieved(responseOne)
            delegator.requestTwo()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())          // <----------------------
        }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
                {responseTwo-> homeScreenCallBack.onResponseTwoRecieved(responseTwo)},
                {error -> homeScreenCallBack.onError()}
        )
```

Comment: Ok would homeScreenCallBack.onResponseOneRecieved(responseOne) be made in the mainThread whilst the delegator.requestTwo be made in teh schedulars IO thread?

Comment: my second request in flat map throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: @pouya do you have the `subscribeOn` inside `flatMap` like my example?

Comment: @akarnokd yes that was the problem it is worth pointing out that we need two `observeOn` and two `subscribeOn` .thanks